# Database of Facebook profile photos

Tags: social-media, faces, large-datasets, photographs

Does there already exists a data set containing, for at least 100 individual people, the photos in their facebook profiles (or their profiles at the time of collection)? I want to use these some facebook profiles for a study and also potentially in marketing, but of course permission is required from each individual. It would be a pain to reach out to potentially thousands of people and get them to sign forms agreeing for their photos to be used, so I was wondering if there already exists such a dataset in which everyone represented in the data set already legally agreed for their photos to be used by any 3rd party.

Comment: If you get your photos from https://www.thispersondoesnotexist.com/ there are no personality rights to consider (but I don't know about the licensing terms)

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be pictures from Facebook? Would pictures from another social network be OK?

Comment: It does not have to be facebook necessarily. I mentioned facebook because I would want photos of the same person in various environments, and facebook profiles tend to contain photos of the same person in various settings. If there were other people in their photos I would obviously also crop them out or otherwise blur them if their permission was not already given. Essentially, the crux of it is that I would need photos of the same person in various settings. If there is a database for another social media site then that is fine too.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul It does not absolutely have to be facebook pictures. Please see my previous comment

Comment: Would you mind modifying your question to reflect all of that? Comments get deleted. Also, is it for use in machine learning? If yes, then AI-generated data might not be ideal.